# JQ newbie trouble selecting nested keys

Tags: json, nested, key, jq

Hi I am new to JQ and Json. I am using

$ jq --version
jq-1.5

I am having a heck of a time trying to figure out how to select the values for id, attributes.name, attributes.albumName, and attributes.artistName

I am using the terminal app on a mac. I am running into some sort strange parsing problem

```
$ jq '.results.songs.data[0] | {id, attributes.name } ' t
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected FIELD, expecting '}' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.results.songs.data[0] | {id, attributes.name }                                         
jq: 1 compile error
$
```

This example shows the structure of the data I am trying to filter looks like

```
    $ jq '.results.songs.data[0] | {id, attributes } ' t
{
  "id": "152471393",
  "attributes": {
    "previews": [
      {
        "url": "https://audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com/apple-assets-us-std-000001/AudioPreview71/v4/7d/c5/68/7dc56849-29b8-bd90-2bb1-51750e479569/mzaf_4742389090778091050.plus.aac.p.m4a"
      }
    ],
    "artwork": {
      "width": 1449,
      "height": 1449,
      "url": "https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/7d/01/56/7d0156be-12cd-8724-a0ca-727b1013a81d/source/{w}x{h}bb.jpeg",
      "bgColor": "ddcfc4",
      "textColor1": "010100",
      "textColor2": "422f10",
      "textColor3": "2d2a27",
      "textColor4": "614f34"
    },
    "artistName": "Gnarls Barkley",
    "url": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/crazy/152471339?i=152471393",
    "discNumber": 1,
    "genreNames": [
      "Alternative",
      "Music",
      "R&B/Soul",
      "Rock",
      "Soul",
      "Hip-Hop/Rap",
      "Rap",
      "Hip-Hop",
      "Adult Alternative",
      "Neo-Soul",
      "Alternative Rap",
      "Underground Rap"
    ],
    "durationInMillis": 178387,
    "releaseDate": "2006-03-13",
    "name": "Crazy",
    "isrc": "USAT20611041",
    "albumName": "St. Elsewhere",
    "playParams": {
      "id": "152471393",
      "kind": "song"
    },
    "trackNumber": 2
  }
}
```

Thanks

Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your sample JSON as input, the following invocation:

```
jq '{id, name: .attributes.name }' input.json
```

produces:

```
{
  "id": "152471393",
  "name": "Crazy"
}
```

The filter above is short for:

```
{"id" : .id, "name": .attributes.name }
```

In any case, the keys must be appropriately specified.

For future reference, when asking questions on stackoverflow.com, please adhere to the  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve guidelines as much as possible.

Comment: Hi Peak, its not clear to me when or why I would need to use the syntax ` "name" . attributes.name` . I expected to use use .attributes.name